# Implementation AbstractPreferenceInitializer won't get called in my Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, preferences

I want to use the Eclipse mechanism to set default preferences in my RCP application. Therefore I extended the class `AbstractPreferenceInitializer` to set my default preferences:

```java
public class PreferenceInitializer extends AbstractPreferenceInitializer {
  @Override
  public void initializeDefaultPreferences() {
    IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore();
    preferenceStore.setDefault("xyz",  xyz);
    preferenceStore.setDefault("abc", false);
  }
}
```

Then I defined the extension point:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
  <initializer class="com.abc.PreferenceInitializer">
  </initializer>
</extension>
```

But unfortunately, the initializer won't get called during startup (whereas Eclipse's `WorkbenchPreferenceInitializer` will be called).

Can someone give me a hint, what to do, to get this run?

Answer (score 6):

Your preference initializer code won't get called until those default values are needed (rather than on application startup, which I'm guessing was your expectation).

If you have yourself a preference page that contains some FieldEditors using your preference names, your preference initializer will get called *when you go to the Preferences dialog and select that preference page.*

Something along the lines of:

```java
public class MyPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    public void createFieldEditors() {
        Composite parent = getFieldEditorParent();
        addField(new StringFieldEditor(Constants.PREFERENCES.FILE_COMPARE_TOOL_LOCATION, "File compare tool location", parent));
        addField(new StringFieldEditor("xyz", "XYZ Value", parent));
        addField(new BooleanFieldEditor("abc", "Enable the ABC widget", parent));
    }

}
```

And of course, an extension point for the page:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
  <page
        class="whatever.package.MyPreferencePage"
        id="whatever.package.MyPreferencePage"
        name="MyPrefs">
  </page>
</extension>
```